# N1QL Rest API returns 404

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I tried using N1QL Query as a `REST API` endpoint to access the data but was getting a 404 error. Is there anything that needs to be configured in couchbase server to support `N1Q1 Rest API`?

[http://127.0.0.1:8091/query/service?statement=select%20a.name,r.destinationairport,%20count(a.name)%20total_flights%20from%20`travel-sample`%20r%20join%20`travel-sample`%20a%20on%20keys%20r.airlineid%20where%20r.type%20=%22route%22%20and%20a.type=%22airline%22%20group%20by%20r.destinationairport,%20a.name%20order%20by%20r.destinationairport](http://127.0.0.1:8091/query/service?statement=select%20a.name,r.destinationairport,%20count(a.name)%20total_flights%20from%20%60travel-sample%60%20r%20join%20%60travel-sample%60%20a%20on%20keys%20r.airlineid%20where%20r.type%20=%22route%22%20and%20a.type=%22airline%22%20group%20by%20r.destinationairport,%20a.name%20order%20by%20r.destinationairport)

Answer (score 1):

```
The bucket name `travel-sample` has special characters so you need to use escaped identifier (back ticks).
```

Query service is running on 8093 port Also you must send REST API to 8093 port.

You can also try this.

```
curl -v http://localhost:8093/query/service -H "Content-Type: application/json"  -d '{"statement":"select a.name,r.destinationairport,count(a.name) AS total_flights from `travel-sample` r join `travel-sample` a on keys r.airlineid where r.type = "route" and a.type="airline" group by r.destinationairport, a.name order by r.destinationairport", "creds":[{"user":"user","pass":"xxxx"}]}'
```